# Items not showing in recycler view Xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

I am implementing recycler view in my Xamarin android application, But Items are not showing on debugging the application altough the InitData() Method is properly executed.

Here is the mainactivity.cs code in which recycler view is implemented:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace FinalProject_PU.Helper
{
    class Data
    {
        public string IssueImage { get; set; }
        public string UserImage { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }
        public string IssueStatement { get; set; }


        public int GetElevatedDates()
        {
            var ElevatedDays = (IssueDate.Date - DateTime.Now.Date).Days;
            return ElevatedDays;
        }

        public string ElevatedDays
        {
            get { return ElevatedDays; }
            set
            {
                if (GetElevatedDates() == 0)
                {
                    ElevatedDays = "Today";
                }
                else
                {
                    ElevatedDays = GetElevatedDates() + "Days";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Home);

            byte[] arr = Convert.FromBase64String(UserInfoHolder.Profile_pic);

            imgwriteIssue = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.imgwriteIssue);
            imgwriteIssue.Click += delegate
            {
                var i = new Intent(this, typeof(CreateIssue));
                this.StartActivity(i);
            };
            CircleImageView img = FindViewById<CircleImageView>(Resource.Id.circleImageView1);
            Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(arr, 0, arr.Length);
            img.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);



            iconfunds = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.iconFunds);
            iconfunds.Click += Iconfunds_Click;

            notifications = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.iconNotifications);
            notifications.Click += Notifications_Click;

            map = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.iconMap);
            map.Click += Map_Click;

            setting = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.iconSettings);
            setting.Click += Setting_Click;

           

            recycler = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView1);
            recycler.HasFixedSize = true;
            //  layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1, GridLayoutManager.Horizontal, false);
            recycler.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            InitData();
            adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(lstData);
            recycler.SetAdapter(adapter);

            
        }

private async void InitData()
        {
            lstData = await IssueController.FetchPostList();
        }
```

fetchallpost() method fetch all the issues from data and return a list of it.

but it is not showing in recycler view and application is halting in a few seconds after opening Homeactivity.cs

Here is the recycler view adapter class on which my programs breaks automatially

RecyclerViewAdapter.cs

````
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Refractored.Controls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using Android.Content;
using AndroidX.Core.Graphics;

namespace FinalProject_PU.Helper
{
    class RecyclerViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView imageview { get; set; }
        public CircleImageView UserImage { get; set; }
        public TextView UserName { get; set; }
        public TextView IssueDate { get; set; }
        public TextView IssueStatement { get; set; }

        Android.Graphics.Typeface tf;
        //
        // public TextView Description { get; set; }
        public RecyclerViewHolder(Android.Views.View itemView) : base(itemView)
        {
            imageview = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
            UserImage = itemView.FindViewById<CircleImageView>(Resource.Id.imgProfile);
            UserName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvname);
            IssueDate = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvtime);
            IssueStatement = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvinfo);
            //beauttification
            
            /*
            tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "Quicksand-Bold.otf");
            IssueStatement.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Bold);

           
            tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "Quicksand-Bold.otf");
            UserName.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Bold);

           
            tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "Quicksand-Bold.otf");
            IssueDate.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Bold);
            */
        }
    }
    class RecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        private List<Data> lstData = new List<Data>();

        public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Data> lstData)
        {
            this.lstData = lstData;
        }

        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get
            {
                return lstData.Count;
            }
        }

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = holder as RecyclerViewHolder;
            byte[] arr0 = Convert.FromBase64String(lstData[position].IssueImage); //IssueImage
            Bitmap b0 = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(arr0, 0, arr0.Length);
            viewHolder.imageview.SetImageBitmap(b0);
            byte[] arr1 = Convert.FromBase64String(lstData[position].UserImage); //UserImage
            Bitmap b1 = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(arr1, 0, arr1.Length);
            viewHolder.UserImage.SetImageBitmap(b1); //
            viewHolder.UserName.Text = lstData[position].UserName;
            viewHolder.IssueDate.Text = lstData[position].ElevatedDays;
            viewHolder.IssueStatement.Text = lstData[position].IssueStatement;

        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context);
            Android.Views.View itemView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.items, parent, false);
            return new RecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
        }
    }
}```


I have tried debugging the application to see what is causing the problem and it was found out that application is breaking when it reaches on this line in recycler view constructor.
I have made sure that the fetchallpost() method is actually returning list with data.

     imageview = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);

please help me with this
````

Comment: @Nebeel What is lstData? Can you provide one sample at github, I will download your sample to test at my side?

Comment: I have share Data.cs class in code.

Comment: About image path, I suggest you can define int property, `public int IssueImage { get; set; }` then get image by Resource.drawable, finally display image by `vh.Image.SetImageResource(lstData[position].IssueImage);` in OnBindViewHolder. There is one sample that you can take a look [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/android50-recyclerviewer/)

Comment: but we are too fetch images from database which are stored in base64 format.

Comment: Please provide your sample at gtihub, I will download your sample to test, because I can not reproduce your problem.